# Powering an AMC1200 Isolation Amp

Tags: amplifier, isolation

I need to measure a very small current at the high-side of a circuit. The high side is at 3000VDC. The measurement needs to ultimately be in the form of a signal with a peak of no more than 5V, so some isolation is required.

I am tinkering with a TI AMC1200, which is an isolation amplifier. The data sheet for the device is here http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1200.pdf

My question is with regards to powering the amplifier. The data sheet specifies that the high and low side should be powered up to around 5v. So, can I just use 2 different 5V power supplies? I am confused, because the signal being measured will be across a sense resistor, so it will be floating up around 3000v.

Perhaps a diagram is in order...this is what I am trying to explain...
[image: Circuit]

I have built a little test circuit, with 20V on the high side, and 2 separate power supplies as suggested above, but it doesn't do anything.

I know this is probably stupid, but I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Uh.... the working voltage rating of the part you link (AMC1200) is only 1200V. That's 1800V short of your operating point. You cannot use the `Isolation voltage` spec for picking parts, since that is generally a rating for transient events. The key word here is **Working voltage**, which is the isolation voltage the part is specced to withstand on a *continuous* basis.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was stupid of me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using a contactless dc current mechanism like a hall effect sensor: -

[image]

This is the first one I found on the web and I can't vouch for it still being available but I'm sure there are others. Data sheet [here](http://fwbell.com/ckfinder/userfiles/files/CLSM-25M_datasheet_020808.pdf).

Comment: [LEM](http://www.lem.com) makes a lot of Hall effect sensors.  [This is just to pile on references.]

Answer (score 0):

Isolated DC/DC converters are commonly used for powering the "hot" side of the isolation amplifier.  Here's an [example](http://www.murata-ps.com/data/power/ncl/kdc_nmj.pdf) of such power supply.  The output (secondary) is floating with respect to input (secondary).  The secondary side ground could be at 2995V and the secondary side output can be at 3000V.

It's also possible to roll your own isolated power supply like that.  The only trick is finding or making a transformer for it.

There may be other ways of achieving this.

- Zener
- I've heard about floating linear regulators, which generate small supply voltages near the high voltage rail.  May be somebody can chime in on this.

Comment: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/design-note/dn21.pdf on floating the input of  a linear regulator.  Also http://www.circuitstoday.com/floating-regulator

Comment: That supply that was recommended here has a 5kV isolation...but is this working voltage or just for transient events? I don't understand how this spec works for supplies...

Answer (score 0):

I have used an isolation amplifier from Analog Devices (can't remember the number) that included isolated power supplies.  The particular one I used was "three port" - the power input was isolated from both the analog input and the analog output.  I believe they also had two-port amplifiers, where the power supply was common to the input, or to the output.

It may be easier to use something like this, rather than having to make your own isolated power supply.

Comment: The Analog Devices ADuM series is what you're thinking of. Unfortunately, they're all well below the OP's required working voltage. The ADuM5000 (an isolated PC in the ADuM series) has a working voltage rating of 560V peak.

Comment: @ConnorWolf:  The ADuM parts appear to be digital devices.  I do see some parts listed with 3KV or 5KV isolation.  I assumed the OP wanted an analog solution.  The part I used is AD210 - but I see that it is only 2.5 KV, and others in that family are only 1.5KV, so won't do.  The AMC1200 also won't meet the OP's requirement as its working voltage is only 1200.

Comment: @PeterBenned - Gah, you're right, the ADuM series are digital. That's what I get for commenting without checking my memory.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, period.  The common mode operating range for this amp is between -160mV and Vdd1, from the Electrical Characteristics table on page 4 of your data sheet.  Unless you can power the chip at 3000V, you need to use a low side current sense, or an even more dramatic approach, like a linear analog optical isolator on the high side followed by a regular amp.

Unfortunately, you've also exceeded the Absolute Maximum  Vin (which is Vdd1+0.5V), and maybe the Absolute Maximum Vdd1 (If you powered w/ 20V -- I don't quite understand your post.  You're OK there if you used 5V) and so your chip may not be functional any more.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is *specifically* asking how to generate an isolated supply with the direct intention of allowing the input of the isolation amp to float up to the supply voltage.

Comment: Yes Connor, this is what I am asking. As you pointed out above, I cannot use this part, but I still am having trouble finding a good solution for powering any type of amplifier floating at 3kV.